# SQL Server - Searching for ' characters via a [^charlist]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find all email addresses in a column that contain characters that shouldn't be in an email address (e.g. `,` ). The below script is working, however the `'` character should also be filtered out, but I can't seem to get it into the script and have the rest of it work.

```
SELECT top 20 Email FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%[^-0-9a-zA-Z@.!#$%&*+-/=?^_`}{|~]%'
```

I tried adding it in via `''` and `\''` but when I do, I start getting results that contain characters that I had previously filtered out (e.g. emails with a `+` or `.` in, but no undesired character).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Email addresses [can include commas and quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part), although not all providers support the full range of characters.  Given the low cost of sending an email, you could argue there's little value in trying to cleanse supplied addresses.

Comment: @destination-data And definitely not from a SQL query.

Comment: @TT. speaks the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ignoring the underlying "How do I validate an email address?" question because [that's a religious issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-you-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript).

This works for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('''john@example.com'''), ('frank^@example.com'), ('ali%ce@example.com'),('bo\b@example.com')) x (email)
WHERE email LIKE '%[^-0-9a-zA-Z@.!#$%&*+-/=?^_`}{|~'']%'
```

No escaping appears to be necessary here.  If you want to, you could use the optional ESCAPE clause for the `%` and `_` characters which are reserved outside a character list.  The `^` is also reserved as the first character inside a character list as the NOT indicator, so you might want to escape that one, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('''john@example.com'''), ('frank^@example.com'), ('ali%ce@example.com'),('bo\b@example.com')) x (email)
WHERE email LIKE '%[^-0-9a-zA-Z@.!#$\%&*+-/=?\^\_`}{|~'']%' ESCAPE '\'
```

You might find that more explicit about what you're trying to do, so you might consider it to be more maintainable.  However, that escaping isn't strictly necessary.